# R: is it possible to draw a diagram with SemPlot without fitting a model?

Tags: r, visualization, r-lavaan, semplot

The documentation for the SemPlot package doesn't appear to show any way to build a path diagram without passing a model object and the model objects appear to only be the output of fit models in e.g. lavaan. Any way to specify nodes and paths similar to Diagrammar without fitting a model to data?